# Angular [error: NJS-045] @nguniversal/express-engine SSR cannot load node-oracledb binary for Node.js

Tags: angular, docker, server-side-rendering, node-oracledb

I'm working on simple project on Angular:^11 + @nguniversal/express-engine for SSR. In my project I'm trying to create REST-API for dynamic web app on server-side with `OracleDB`[**Docker: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1**].

While Opening pool with oracledb I'm having an error something like as follow:

```
D:\project\server\main.js:149903
      throw new Error(nodbUtil.getErrorMessage('NJS-045', nodeInfo));
      ^

Error: NJS-045: cannot load a node-oracledb binary for Node.js 12.18.3 (win32 x64)
  Looked for D:\project\dist\project\build\Release\oracledb-5.1.0-win32-x64.node, 
  D:\project\dist\project\build\Release\oracledb.node, D:\project\dist\project\build\Debug\oracledb.node, 
  D:\project\dist\project\server\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb-5.1.0-win32-x64.node, 
  D:project\dist\project\server\node_modules\oracledb\build\Release\oracledb.node.....
```

I have tried this class in TypeScript and it worked very well, and angular not.

```js
import * as oracledb from 'oracledb';
import Connections from '../config/connections';

class Database {

  public openConnections = async () => {

    const connection = new Connections().getInfo();
    
    try {

      oracledb.initOracleClient({
        libDir: 'D:\\lib\\instantclient_19_9',
      });

      await oracledb.createPool({
        user: connection.user,
        password: connection.password,
        connectionString: connection.connectString,
        poolAlias: connection.poolAlias,
        poolMin: connection.poolMin,
        poolMax: connection.poolMax,
        poolIncrement: connection.poolIncrement,
      });
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.warn(error);
    }
  }
}
```

I call the Database class in `server.ts` before server creates...

```js
...
...
   endpoints(application);
   await new Database().openConnections();
   server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
   });
}
...
...
```

Are there any problem with this Database class or ... ?

Ref:

```py
Angular CLI: 11.0.5
Node: 12.18.3
Angular: 11.0.5
```

Comment: It seams like you forgot to install [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb), did u run `npm i -g oracledb`

Comment: I did! Error: `NJS-045` comes from `node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js`

Comment: And https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-211-errornum says that eror name `NJS-045` is not `oracledb`'s problem.

Comment: Where exactly are you using Angular?  Node-oracledb doesn't run in Angular - it needs to be in a mid-tier since it needs to load binary libraries.  See https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/957#issuecomment-410264998

Comment: I'm using Angular where express-engine server-side-rendering guided by  angular.io/guide/universal

Comment: Curious if you found an answer to this. I'm running into a similair problem with compiling in a Node.js package that I need to run on my Express Server part of the Angular Universal App. Normally in Express.js it compiles no problem but with express-engine it fails